# Basic Javascript Teletype not working

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to get words to appear one character at a time, but it seems to be eluding my noob-like JavaScript skills. Please can someone set me straight?

Thank you in advance!

```js
var str1 = "Hello World!";
var str2 = "";
 
for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  str2 += str1.slice(i, i + 1);
  document.getElementById("stringy").innerHTML = str2;
 }, 200);
};
```

```html
<div id="stringy"></div>
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; ..... restOfYourCode`  A demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/tk2ssjmr/

Comment: You are setting the timeout from 200 ms from when the `for` executes, which means all at once. try `setTimeout(..., 200*i);`

Comment: **which means all at once** No, it would be executed one after other. But not with any interval gap.